# Can the Firefox DevTools Inspector highlight be made sticky?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm spending some time writing HTML and CSS, and am using the developer tools in Firefox 53. Specifically, the "HTML/DOM/CSS Inspector".

When you move the mouse over a chunk of HTML in the Inspector window, the corresponding rendered HTML element on the page is highlighted.  Plus, there are some helpful grid lines and color overlays and whatnot also drawn over the page, all of which was a good decision on the part of the Mozilla developers. It shows how random `div`s and other elements might be overlapping, is great for showing where margins are collapsing, etc.

However, when I move the mouse off the HTML tree, all that useful highlighting and overlays vanish. **Is there a way to get that highlighting/overlay to "stick"?** For example, until I click on another HTML element, or reload the page, or... actively take some action other than simply moving my mouse?

Note that right-clicking the Inspector and selecting the ":hover" menu entry is most emphatically *not* what I'm looking for.  I want to change the mouseover behavior *of the Inspector*, not that of the *page*.

(Now I'm going to pour another shot of whiskey and resume fighting with the Rules/Computed-versus-"browser styles" controls.  Those were... not as well designed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general highlighter can't be toggled to stay on the page, it only reacts on hovering the nodes.

Only some other highlighters are sticky, like the one for elements matching a specific CSS selector or the CSS grid highlighter, both located within the *Rules* side panel:

[image: Selector matching and grid highlighter within the *Rules* side panel]

The CSS selector matching highlighter is currently (as of Firefox 53) the one that comes nearest to what you're looking for, though it's missing the grid lines.

Furthermore, there is already a [request for adding a sticky element highlighter in Mozilla's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1180204).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'll look elsewhere and see if some other browser has ever implemented this, although I suspect the answer will be "no" as it just doesn't seem like a common request.  The linked Mozilla feature request does not fill me with excitement; I got as far as _Reported: 2 years ago_ and gave up hope that it would happen by FF56.

Comment: Lately I saw an issue that got fixed 12 years after it got filed! That doesn't mean, this one will also take that long, though it means implementation always depends on priorities. So, to support its implementation, you should vote for it or outline your use case in a comment, (or provide a patch for it :-) ).

Comment: Also note, that the bug was filed by someone of the DevTools team, which probably makes it somewhat more likely that it gets implemented at some point. Furthermore, the request to have sticky highlighting is obviously more common as you think, because a [similar question got asked on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1221703/324429) yesterday.